# Как в Sublime можно перемещаться между множественные курсорами?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, atom

Есть 4 курсора, выделенные с помощью Ctrl+d. Как можно быстро перемещаться между ними? Для примера: написать this, а потом между курсорами перемещаться какой-нибудь комбинацией.

в итоге должно получиться:

this.edit

this.delete

this.save

this.cancel

[image: Multi]

Comment: таб не помогает?

Comment: таб удаляет все

Comment: **https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MultiEditUtils**

Comment: оооо спасибо)) жаль в атоме такого нет

Answer (score 0):

ctrl Alt стрелки верх вниз это и linux windows

Comment: совсем не то :/. Я имел в виду Use selections as fields как в MultiEditUtils для Sublime

Answer (score 0):

Здесь даже графически не понятно что должно происходить - все курсоры одинаковые.

А вообще есть такая фича: Устанавливаете плагин Emmet, создаете шаблонный html документ. Далее набираете в body например **div.container>div.item*3>a[href="here"]** и жмете Tab. Курсор окажется в первой ссылке - набираете текст ссылки и чтобы быстро перейти к набору следующего жмете Tab. Profit!

Читаем далее тут: https://nicothin.github.io/sublime-text/sublime-text-3-hotkeys.html

Comment: Я имел в виду как здесь. https://packagecontrol.io/readmes/img/df2edde045082915e1acd8a0ed41dbae839cad55.gif

Comment: классная вещь, я о такой даже не знал...  спасибо за подсказку!!!

Answer (score 0):

есть MultiEditUtils для Sublime https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MultiEditUtils

Пункт "Use selections as fields"